# Is it a good idea to upload video in base64 using REST API?

Tags: ruby, api, rest, ruby-on-rails-4, carrierwave

I am using carrierwave with Rails-4 and to upload images using REST APIs I am using base64 encoding and decoding technique.

I would like to know if we can apply the same method with video upload also or is there a better way to upload videos from Mobile app using REST API?

Your help would be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: The most obvious alternative is to just upload the binary data. Is there a reason you can't do that?

Comment: No there is no specific that I can't do that, I was just curious if Rails has good support for that.

Comment: Although there's not "built-in" support, it would be easy to do in Rails. However, it will be much easier not to do. Rails handles binary uploads automatically.

Answer (score 3):

Base64 encoding will greatly increase the bandwidth used.  Uploading the binary file would be faster and conserve both mobile bandwidth and the battery.